# CSS Positioning Above all elements

Tags: html, css, graphics, position

So I have a small login box that appears when clicking the login button. The problem is that when it appears, it appears behind everything else on the page. This is what it looks like:
[image: Login]

How do I make the login box ALWAYS appears above anything on a page?

Comment: Increase z-index of your popup css.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some code would be nice... anyway try with z-index:

```
#login-box-id {
    z-index:99999;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelBenneton you're welcome ;) provide a fiddle or some example code next time!

Comment: Note that this will not always work. If the 2 elements have different `position` for example.

Answer (score 1):

you need to apply some z-indexing,

I assume you have a position set to either absolute or relative or fixed, if so, add this too

```
z-index:2;
```

If you want more help please provide some CSS/html and i can show you exactly where it needs to go.